# Selenium::WebDriverでphantomjsを使っている時のHTTPヘッダーの確認方法

Tags: ruby, http, phantomjs

`Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs`で作成したDriverクラスが特定のページにアクセスする際のHTTPヘッダーを確認したいのですが、どうすれば見られますか？

ChromeやFirefoxの場合は開発ツールを使えば確認できるのですが、Phantomjsの時はどうすれば見れるかを調べられませんでした。

PC全体のパケットを監視するなどの方法しかないのでしょうか？